# Data split into training and test

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, train

I am implementing an EEG classifier with 15 subjects (patients), specifically a support vector machine classifier.

I randomly choose the training and testing sets, but I was faced by a question "how did you choose subjects in each set?". I looked for the response but I couldn't find a good one (cross validation wouldn't be the best solution in my case).

Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Why wouldn't cross validation be if not the best at least a better solution than a random one time split of the data? Just splitting once is a highly inefficient use of the data. 

And why couldn't you answer the question? If you assigned randomly isn't that the answer to the question?

Comment: the question was why did you choose this subjects for training and not other one, and when i tried to choose other subjects performences were a litle bit less then the firts ones. and the cross validation process wouldn't be the best solution because my data is huge one and then cross validation will be a very long process. i was wondreing if there is statsticals tests that i can use to have an idea about the data?

Comment: Well, you changed the split and got other results. Assessing the variability of classifier performance is exactly one of the advantages cross validation offered. And since you tried out two splits out already I somehow doubt that 10-fold cross-validation is not possible. Are you thinking of leave-one-out cv?

Comment: could you please explain more about how leave one out Cv will help me more? i used LOO-CV for other purpose (to compare three features with LDA classifier) but i was told that the LOO-Cv could only be used in small data sets isn't it?

Comment: I did not suggest to use it. I was wondering if you think about it when you say CV is not feasible because your data set is too large. As I cannot really imagine a scenario where building a model once (twice in your case) is fast enough but doing it ten times (10-fold CV) suddenly becomes impossible.

Comment: Suppose you have $n$ observations. LOO-CV takes 1 observation out of your data set and uses all the others to train your model. Measures how well it predicted on the left out(LO) observation. Then it takes another observation wich is not the previous one and uses all the others to train your model. Measures how well this model predicts on this LO observation. Does this $n$ times. The error would be the average of all these measures. 10-fold separates your observations into 10 groups $|g1|+|g2|+...+|g10|=n$. Uses the groups 1 to 9 to train, tests on $g10$. Does this 10 times. A shorter process.

Comment: As you say that you have 15 subjects, but a large data set: do you have many repeated measurements per subject/patient? In that case, the question may have been aimed at whether you did split (randomly) *patients* [correct] or *measurements* [optimistically biased].

Comment: i have an 8 hour record for each patient and i have to dived data into 30sec epochs, so the result is relatively big. i'm trying to implement the LOO procedure now i will tell you about what i found

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are seeking to classify the EEG data into one or more disease states e.g. seizure/non-seizure, pathological/non-pathological etc.

The best way to validate a classifier model for an application like this is to implement Leave One Out cross validation.

What I mean by this is to start with all data for patient 1 as the test set and all data for patients 2-15 as the training set and store the results. Next, set the data for patient 2 as the test set and the remainder as the training set. Do this for each patient's data in turn so that you have 15 classification results, one for each patient. The take the mean of these 15 values and you have an estimate for the classification performance of your classifier model on unseen data.

Comment: IMHO leave-one-out is certainly not the *best* way to validate such data. Iterated/repeated $k$-fold or leave-$n$-out (with $k$ < no of cases / $n$ > 1) is certainly better, as is out-of-bootstrap. Nevertheless, LOO is a sensible starting point for someone not familiar with resampling validation.

Comment: @cbeleites, agreed, but was trying to provide a solid starting point for a newcomer to the area